# Finding the best way to pull the last 7 days with Impala when datetime is string

Tags: impala

I am trying to work with a dataset that we started pulling in and of course the "devicereceipttime" is stored as a string, and I cant convince anyone to change it right now.  However the "year", "month", "day" and "hour" are broken out into separate fields as "ints".  It looks like the following:

```
devicereceipttime(string)   year(int)  month(int)  day(int)  hour(int)
2018-06-19T05:00:06.265Z    2018       6           19        5
2018-06-19T18:53:56.776Z    2018       6           19        6
2018-06-19T02:10:05.252Z    2018       6           19        2
2018-06-19T12:14:01.395Z    2018       6           19        12
```

I am using Impala and would like to run a query similar to the one below but one that would work with the types above either just using the "devicereceipttime" string value or the "y/m/d" ints.  I am looking to capture a whole week(7 consecutive days) so I will probably schedule reports to run in CDSW on Saturdays or Mondays.

This a query I was using when the datetime string format was "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

```
select *  
from winworkstations_realtime 
where devicereceipttime BETWEEN concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), " 00:00:00") and concat(to_date(now() - interval 8 days), " 24:00:00")
```

Would it be better to use the string or try to figure it out with a bunch of ints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this to satisfy the query:

```
devicereceipttime BETWEEN concat(to_date(now() - interval 7 days), "T00:00:00.000Z") and concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), "T23:59:59.999Z")

select w.destinationhostname,w.destinationusername, w.destinationprocessname, count(*) as count \
from winworkstations_realtime w \
where w.devicereceipttime BETWEEN concat(to_date(now() - interval 7 days), "T00:00:00.000Z") and concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), "T23:59:59.999Z") AND w.externalid="4688" AND w.destinationhostname like "T%" AND (w.destinationusername not like "%$" AND w.destinationusername not like "LOCAL%" AND w.destinationusername not like "-") \
group by w.destinationhostname, w.destinationusername,w.destinationprocessname \
order by 1,2'
```